# Ascertain the pixels in a convex hull 2D

Tags: algorithm, 2d, convex-hull, convex

I have some pixels which representing already a convex hull, now I looking for a way to calculate these pixels to fill the convex hull.
Is there any algorithm or idea which I should look at?

Comment: So you already have the convex hull, but you need a fill algorithm?

Comment: I assume you already have the convex hull in a bitmap then?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but not directly in a bitmap.

Comment: In that case, a simple search should have told you more than enough about flood fill algorithms and how to implement them. take a look at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Flood_fill